# How to delete a hacked score from Google Play Game Services leaderboard?

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have a leaderboard with tamper protection ON since it's creation, but a player has added a hacked score of some millions of points (human reachable max of points is less than 1000)

How can I delete only that hacked score? It must be a way to do it... but can't find in documentation: https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [players.hide()](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide) call. This will hide a player and all of his/her scores from the public leaderboard so that nobody else can see them.

Note that this REST call is not built into the mobile libraries; you'll need to create your own mini web app (or make curl calls directly) to use this call, although there is a management tools sample app that you can use [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools) which might make your life easier.

Oh, and if you know that the human reachable high score has to be 1000 max, specify a "Max score" of 1000 for that leaderboard in the Play Games Console.

Comment: The management-tools seems not working any more... Wish someone can have an update of it...

Answer (score 2):

What I do is some kind of obfuscation.

I mean, I do replace numbers with an string like

```
0 = #$%@&*52$*@ 
1 = #$%@&*84$*$
2 = #$%@&*58$*#
```

separated for another unique string like: %$$90&*
and so on.

so when I go to post the score, first I do a find and replace
the string for each number, as I am posting the score locally the 
data would look like;

```
122 = #$%@&*84$*$%$$90&*#$%@&*58$*#%$$90&*#$%@&*58$*#
```

so its a little bit difficult (not impossible) to post a hacked score

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Developers OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=api-project-790263402012) to do the players.hide() as mentioned by @todd-kerpelman, following the instruction in [this article](https://gaute.app/dev-blog/gpgs-hide-player), but it is still a very tedious process.

I used the [management-tools](https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools) before too, but it seems to be not working any more.